# How do I hide certain elements on my page, based on referral traffic?

Tags: javascript

More specifically, how do I hide ads? I pose this question after reading this:
[coding horror entry](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/how-to-advertise-on-your-blog-without-completely-selling-out.html)

In it, he states

> As a courtesy, turn off ads for Digg, Reddit, and other popular
>   referring URLs. This audience doesn't appreciate ads, and they're the
>   least likely to click them anyway.

I agree with what he says. So how do I do this?

Comment: With PHP (you have to do serverside), you can detect the referrer with `$_SERVER['referrer']` or something like that. You'll have to use a serverside language to do it, as JavaScript can't access that information.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate (if you know?) As I barely know PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use PHP for this, as JavaScript code to hide ads will make you look like you're hiding the ads for everyone and just gaining revenue from them (Google is smart, so they'll find you for doing something like that).

With PHP, however, you can modify the page *before* it reaches the user, eliminating that problem. Basically, you conditionally check where the browser came from:

```
<?php
  $sites = array("reddit.com", "digg.com");

  if (!in_array(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST), $sites)) :
?>

  <div>your ads</div>

<?php else:?>

  <div>Hello reddit person</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You'll have to make your site run PHP code (it'll be dynamic) to conditionally display your ads. This code won't work, though, as `reddit` isn't a URL, but you get the idea; check the URL for `reddit.com`.

Comment: Ah. This is interesting. Did you mispell REFERRER? And, as asked above, would this work on stumbleupon traffic (if you know what stumbleupon is)?

Comment: No, that's the way it's spelled in PHP's twisted world. As for stumbleupon, let me edit that in.

Comment: @Blender: It's spelled that way in the HTTP spec.

Comment: @alex: Hm, didn't know that. I knew one of those spellings seemed odd. But [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer#Origin_of_the_term_referer) that it's a misspelling too.

Comment: Blender, you sure? The reason why I've been pressing this is because stumbleupon delivers traffic in an odd fashion. Every stumbleupon user has the stumbleupon toolbar, and when he/she clicks the 'stumble' button in the toolbar, it activates a javascript code which brings the user to a "random" page. This is all very confusing, I know hah. Still though, I'm going to use your code, thanks!

Comment: The stumbleupon bar is a webpage with an iframe on the bottom. Think of it like a proxy's navigation menu.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know how ads are handled on your site, but on StackOverflow it might be something akin to

```
function hideAds()
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName( "everyonelovesstackoverflow" )
    for( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) 
          elems[ i ].parentNode.removeChild( elems[ i ] )
}
// change the logic as you like. You may need to parse document.referrer
if( document.referrer == <some referrer url> ) hideAds()
```

Comment: Well, I'm using adsense ads. And my site is not dynamic in any way. Also, I do not know anything about javascript so pardon what I'm about to ask :(. (I Just know html and css really well).

The ad script goes inside where "everyonelovestackoverflow", right?
The referral url would work on digg.com, reddit.com, I would think. But what about stumbleupon? Since stumbleupon? If you don't know what stumbleupon is, it might be hard for you to understand why I'm posing this question.

Comment: @user What do you mean your site isn't dynamic?

Comment: Well you said, "I don't know how ads are handled on your site". I'm just saying my site works like a plain site. It isn't handled in any complex way.

Comment: @user Basically, the idea is that you test document.referrer, if that looks like it comes from one of the sites in your list, then do something to stop the ads from displaying (in this case, remove them completely from the dom).

Comment: Hmm, well do you know what stumbleupon is? If so, do you think it'll detect stumbleupon as a referrer?

Comment: @user: Referrer is the webpage from which you came from. It should work for almost any site.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to show ads if appropriate, not hide ads if inappropriate -- or else you are probably violating the terms of AdSense, e.g. hiding ads after they're displayed. At the very least, wait to display the ads until you check the referrer (may also be violating the terms, but much less likely). Also review the terms of your ad service to ensure that using a client-side technology like javascript to dynamically display ads is not against the terms.

To answer your question, just detect the HTTP Referrer (the field is actually called the HTTP "Referer", which is a misspelling) and insert ads if it's not from the websites you "like". For API / examples, you can google for `http referrer your_language`. For example, in PHP it is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. In python, it depends on the web framework you're using. As someone else mentions in javascript it is `document.referrer`, etc. Javascript is the easiest solution, but once again, read the terms.